# Trendline conditional formatting

Tags: excel, charts

I wasn't successful in finding a solution to my question by googling it, so i hope here there are experts that can help.

I just have one set of data over time (the number of actions per date, so for one month, two columns and 30 rows). I am using a clustered column chart to visualize that data, and have placed a trendline on it.

I would like to change the color of the trendline dynamicaly, to RED if it it descending, or GREEN if ascending. That's it.

Whatever option I tried in Excel 2013, I haven't found the solution, and programmaticaly, I am too "dummy".

Comment: Does ascending/descending refer to the total trend for all 30 points, or do you want it colored in segments based on the difference between consecutive points?  Option 1 (overall trend) is fairly straightforward.  Option 2 (segmented coloring) is not possible (so far as I know) without breaking the data up and creating trendlines for each segment.  That might be possible with VBA but would certainly be a mess.  A picture of your chart or a visual explanation may also prove helpful for us.

Answer (score 0):

I have an approach that skips the built-in trendline. You calculate your own slope, intercept, and correlation, plot your own trendline(s), and use your own formula in the chart. In fact, you have two lines to go with your columns, one that appears if the slope is positive and the other if the slope is negative.

Here's how:

[image]

In the screenshot above I have your data in columns A and B. I calculate some statistics as follows:

- cell G2: =SLOPE(B2:B12,ROW(B2:B12))
- cell G3: =INTERCEPT(B2:B12,ROW(B2:B12))
- cell G4: =CORREL(B2:B12,ROW(B2:B12))

I generate the formula in cell G6:

="Y = "&TEXT(G3,"0.0000")&" + "&TEXT(G2,"0.0000")&" * X"&CHAR(10)&"R² = "&TEXT(G4^2,"0.0000")

The superscript "²" is inserted by holding Alt while typing 0178 on the numeric keypad. "0.0000" is the format I'm using to display the cell values in the formula; without using the TEXT function, you'll get something with way too many digits to be useful.

The formulas in C2 and D2 (copied down the column as needed) are:

- cell C2: =IF($G$2>0,$G$3+$G$2*ROW(),NA())
- cell D2: =IF($G$2<0,$G$3+$G$2*ROW(),NA())

Because of the IF and the NA(), you get values only in one column and #N/A errors (which won't plot in a line chart) in the other, depending on slope.

Create a clustered column chart using all four columns, then change the chart type of the two trend series to line chart. Format the columns and lines as desired.

Select the title by its border, so the cursor isn't in the text of the title. Type =, then click on the cell with the formula. This link will cause the title to update if the formula changes. Change the title text size from huge to something reasonable.

Delete the legend if desired. In this case it really isn't needed.